# Is it possible to use Visual Studio to compile and debug with GCC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, visual-studio-2022

Is it doable? and how? I've been searching but the closest I could find was "use GCC in Visual Studio for Linux development" and stuff about Android SDK. What I want is simply compile / debug / run on Windows (Using Visual Studio. not VS Code).

Comment: Visual studio uses gcc compiler by default for c/c++ codes. For further insurance, you can check compiler settings and if the compiler is not gcc then just select gcc.

Comment: @AbdurRakib _"Visual studio uses gcc compiler by default for c/c++"_: huh???